# How can I append search results to a div tag and then overwrite the contents on the next search?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have tried searching for an answer but I'm not sure how one would phrase the question, so I have had no luck find it.

So please forgive me if there is an answer lying around already ^_^

I'm using XMLHttpRequest() to get JSON data from: http://api.mtgapi.com
and displaying the results in a div tag with the id 'demo'

all works fine and the results are appended at the bottom.
However I would like for further results to overwrite the previous ones as supposed to appending it at the bottom.
I have tried using:

```
document.getElementById("demo").value = " ";
```

but sadly i havn't gotten any where. Can someone suggest something?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Magic the Gathering</title>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var searching = document.getElementById("search");
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (window.location.protocol != "https:"){
        var url= 'http://api.mtgapi.com/v2/cards?name=' + searching.value;
    }
    else{
        var url= 'https://api.mtgapi.com/v2/cards?name=' + searching.value;
    }
    console.log(url);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

            for (i = 0; i < myArr.cards.length; i++){
                var para = document.createElement("P");
                var br = document.createElement("br");
                var att = document.createAttribute("id");
                att.value = i;
                para.setAttribute("id", i);
                console.log(para);
                para.innerHTML = 
                "Artist: " + myArr.cards[i].artist + "<br />" + 
                "Border: " + myArr.cards[i].border + "<br /> "+
                "Colour: " + myArr.cards[i].colors + "<br /> " +
                "Original Text: " + myArr.cards[i].originalText + "<br /> " +
                "Original Type: " + myArr.cards[i].originalType + "<br />" +
                "Power: " + myArr.cards[i].power + "<br />";
                document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(para);
                document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(br);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Magic the Gathering</h2>

<h4>Search Magic Api</h4>
<form method="post" action="#" name="magicapi">
Search Api: <input type="text" id="search" name="search" value="">
<input type ="button" name ="mtgapi" onclick='myFunction()' value ="search mtg api">
</form>

<div id="demo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just an FYI, the HTML specification says you can reduce this `if (window.location.protocol != "https:"){
        var url= 'http://api.mtgapi.com/v2/cards?name=' + searching.value;
    }
    else{
        var url= 'https://api.mtgapi.com/v2/cards?name=' + searching.value;
    }` to simply `var url= '//api.mtgapi.com/v2/cards?name=' + searching.value;`

Comment: `myArr.cards.length` is undefined for values where no cards are returned.  You should check `if (myArr && myArr.cards)` prior to using the length.  You can also access `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<br/>" + myArr.query[0].value + " Not Found" + "<br/>";` for an example in an else for the if when that is the case.  Codepen example: http://codepen.io/MarkSchultheiss/pen/zqbKzx?editors=1010  Enter a value "Jace" to see that work and "Jace, the Mind Sculptor" to see it return something.

Comment: One other thing, your form has "post" so if you type a value in the search, then press the enter key, it posts instead of using your ajax as the button click does.

Comment: NOTE Be really careful of my previous comment if someone enters `<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>` for a search value, the alert occurs. i.e. Script can run.  Use `.textContent` to do that instead of `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `innerHTML` instead of `value`:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: It works thank you, though strangely, when I put the javascript in a different file, even with your answer it still appends it to the div tag. But I'll figure it out